# Join another table with condition in a SELECT DISTINCT ON statement Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

My head is spinning on a solution to the following...
I have a working query which gets me the rows with the first create_date along with my specified conditions. Now i want to expand that query and join another table event and then distinct filter all records with an event 'signup'.

The question I want to answer with my query is which users had a firsthit with refererpath '/community%' and so on and then further filter which of those had then an event 'signup'. The first part I solve with my working query, but how to i redefine it to get back only the users with a signup action based on that? I'm on postgres.

**My working query for the first part:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (cookie_hash) cookie_hash, crdate, http_referer, refererpath
FROM trace t1
WHERE crdate = (SELECT MIN(crdate) FROM trace t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
AND refererpath LIKE '/community%' AND http_referer IS NOT NULL AND http_referer NOT LIKE 'https://example.io%'
ORDER BY cookie_hash, crdate
```

**What i tried:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (cookie_hash) t1.cookie_hash, t1.crdate, t1.http_referer, t1.refererpath
FROM trace t1
INNER JOIN event on t1.cookie_hash = event.cookie_hash
WHERE t1.crdate = (SELECT MIN(crdate) FROM trace t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
AND refererpath LIKE '/community%' AND http_referer IS NOT NULL AND http_referer NOT LIKE 'https://example.io%'
AND event.action = 'signup'
ORDER BY cookie_hash, crdate
```

This one gives me back wrong results with traces that had an signup event before my specified conditions :/

**My two tables have this structure:**

**Table trace:**

```
+--------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| Column       | Type                        | Modifiers                               |
|--------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------|
| id           | integer                     |  not null                               |
| cookie_hash  | character varying(255)      |  default NULL::character varying        |
| crdate       | timestamp(0) with time zone |  default NULL::timestamp with time zone |
| action       | character varying(255)      |  default NULL::character varying        |
| account_uuid | character varying(255)      |  default NULL::character varying        |
+--------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

**And table event:**

```
+-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| Column          | Type                        | Modifiers                               |
|-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------|
| id              | integer                     |  not null                               |
| cookie_hash     | character varying(255)      |  default NULL::character varying        |
| crdate          | timestamp(0) with time zone |  default NULL::timestamp with time zone |
| remote_addr     | character varying(255)      |  default NULL::character varying        |
| refererhost     | text                        |                                         |
| refererpath     | text                        |                                         |
| http_referer    | text                        |                                         |
| account_uuid    | character varying(255)      |  default NULL::character varying        |
+-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

**Here is some sample data for more details on the Problem:**

I used the query provided by the answer of Gordon Linoff... But it's also not working as expected, not all of my returned data is properly correct.

Many of the rows in my result do not contain the first/earliest timestamp.
This is returned row which works as expected:

```
| 3d16632fe65e2155db0bd3304bae8ad2 | 2019-01-31 15:01:38+00 | signup   | https://www.google.com/                                                        | /community/....                               |                           |
```

**When i search this cookie_hash in my trace table i can prove it with this:**

```
+---------+----------------------------------+------------------------+---------------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id      | cookie_hash                      | crdate                 | remote_addr   | uri    | refererhost     | refererscheme   | refererquery   | refererfragment   | refererpath                                              | http_referer            | http_user_agent                                                                                            
|---------+----------------------------------+------------------------+---------------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1182240 | 3d16632fe65e2155db0bd3304bae8ad2 | 2019-01-31 15:01:38+00 | xxx | <null> | example.io    | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /community/.... | https://www.google.com/ | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.2 Saf
| 1182241 | 3d16632fe65e2155db0bd3304bae8ad2 | 2019-01-31 15:01:47+00 | xxx | <null> | ....io | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /signup/                                                 | <null>                  | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.2 Saf
| 1182248 | 3d16632fe65e2155db0bd3304bae8ad2 | 2019-01-31 15:04:52+00 | xxx | <null> | example.io    | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /community/.... | https://www.google.com/ | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.2 Saf
+---------+----------------------------------+------------------------+---------------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But many of the returned rows are incorrect, i get back cookie_hashes who dont have a first hit like '/community%' and a http_referer with NULL... Take a look at this sample row:

```
| 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 11:46:49+00 | signup   | https://www.google.de/                                                         | /community/.../.../                                       |
```

**When i look up this trace in the trace table i get the following results:**

```
+--------+----------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id     | cookie_hash                      | crdate                 | remote_addr                           | uri    | refererhost     | refererscheme   | refererquery   | refererfragment   | refererpath                                       | http_referer                    | http_user_agent                                                                    
|--------+----------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 528636 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 09:03:12+00 | xxx | <null> | example.io    | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /                                                 | <null>                          | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 528637 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 09:03:19+00 | xxx | <null> | example.io    | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /                                                 | https://example.io/           | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 528638 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 09:03:30+00 | xxx | <null> | example.io    | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /bla/team/                                        | https://example.io/           | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 528690 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 09:24:47+00 | xxx | <null> | my.example.io | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /                                                 | <null>                          | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 528692 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 09:26:01+00 | xxx | <null> | my.example.io | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /signup/                                          | <null>                          | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 528693 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 09:26:06+00 | xxx | <null> | my.example.io | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /                                                 | <null>                          | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 528695 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 09:26:13+00 | xxx | <null> | my.example.io | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /signup/                                          | <null>                          | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 528700 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 09:26:41+00 | xxx | <null> | my.example.io | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /xxx/                                           | <null>                          | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 528701 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 09:27:17+00 | xxx | <null> | my.example.io | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /ValidateSuccess                                  | <null>                          | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 528702 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 09:27:22+00 | xxx | <null> | my.example.io | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /xxx/                                           | <null>                          | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 528703 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 09:27:45+00 | xxx | <null> | my.example.io | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /                                                 | <null>                          | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 528705 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 09:27:56+00 | xxx | <null> | example.io    | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /community/.../                                   | <null>                          | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 528721 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 09:30:45+00 | xxx | <null> | example.io    | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /bla/team/                                        | <null>                          | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 528847 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 10:41:34+00 | xxx | <null> | example.io    | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /                                                 | <null>                          | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 528848 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 10:41:38+00 | xxx | <null> | example.io    | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /bla/team/                                        | https://example.io/           | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 528999 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 11:46:49+00 | xxx | <null> | example.io    | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /community/.../.../                               | https://www.google.de/      | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 529016 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 11:57:00+00 | xxx | <null> | example.io    | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /                                                 | <null>                          | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 529017 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 11:57:04+00 | xxx                         | <null> | example.io    | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /                                                 | <null>                          | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 529171 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 13:15:59+00 | xxx | <null> | example.io    | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /                                                 | <null>                          | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 529172 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 13:16:02+00 | xxx | <null> | example.io    | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /bla/                                       | https://example.io/           | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
| 529173 | 9edf070706c8a728cc78719befc6cdd7 | 2018-01-08 13:16:04+00 | xxx | <null> | example.io    | https           | <null>         | <null>            | /bla/team/                                  | https://example.io/bla/ | Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Ge
+--------+----------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Do you maybe have another idea? I updated my question with more information..

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to filter *after* the `distinct on`?

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (cookie_hash) t1.cookie_hash, t1.crdate, event.action, t1.http_referer, t1.refererpath
      FROM (SELECT t1.*, MIN(crdate) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as min_crdate
            FROM trace t1
           ) t1 INNER JOIN
           event 
           ON t1.cookie_hash = event.cookie_hash
      WHERE t1.crdate = t1.min_crdate AND
            refererpath LIKE '/community%' AND
            http_referer IS NOT NULL AND
            http_referer NOT LIKE 'https://example.io%'
      ORDER BY cookie_hash, crdate;
     ) x
WHERE action = 'signup'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question and provided some samples, i tried your query, but it is also not working right

Comment: @aura199x . . . Try it with the `ORDER BY` in the subquery, where it belongs.